Has Russia ever condemned Hezbollah attacks on Israel?
I know they condemned Hamas' attacks on Oct 7, and in the same breath also condemned Israel's response.
More recently, Russia condemned the Israeli response to Hezbollah. But unlike in the statements on Oct 7, I don't see [at least in what I read] any condemnation of Hezbollah's actions by Russia.
So, did the Russian government ever condemn Hezbollah attacks on Israel? I mean explicitly, not in general, both-sides terms like decrying the "the spiral of violence" in the region. If so, when was roughly the last time Russia's government said something about Hezbollah's actions?

(Today Russia released another statement that Israel must 'immediately' withdraw their troops from Lebanon.)

FWTW, I found this from July 2006, which was probably prompted by the Hezbollah infiltration into Israel then:

Russian Defense Minister Sergei Ivanov said Saturday that Hezbollah should “stop resorting to any terrorist methods, including attacking neighboring states.”

I'm not sure if they've been so blunt since then.
